# MySQL a query to get user_id and password from two different tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

- Professeur (professeur_id, name , password,mail)
- Student (student_id, name, password, mail)

How can I write a query to get ID and password from the two tables?

Also, can I make a login table that contains ID and password as a foreign key from the two tables?

(Do I have to change the professeur ID and student ID columns to have the same name?)

Comment: You may also create a SQL view, that would have the relevant data from both tables.

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags. If this could be solved (or broken) entirely from a servlet or a command line app, it's safe to say it has nothing to do with Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Look here about "join": https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's not a join, it's a union select.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union select:

```
select
  p.professeur_id as id
  , p.name as name
  , p.password as password
  , p.mail as mail
  from Professeur p
union select
  s.student_id as id
  , s.name as name
  , s.password as password
  , s.mail as mail
  from Student s
  ;
```

Please note that at least the fields professeur_id and student_id ***must*** have an alias because of their different name. But giving all fields an alias is a good practice.

For more information (not only on select statement) please go to [official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)